# Can't connect to a server via SSH (with my PC only)

Tags: linux, ssh, git

For some days I'm experiencing issues with SSH on my machine (I guess after having installed some softs that I don't remember... (sic))

It's very problematic as **I use Git** to work on some code projects with other people, pushing my work on a repository via SSH.

I'm 100 % sure the problem is coming from my computer (Linux Mint 16 cinnamon), because:

- From the same Internet connexion (same router, same IP), I can connect without any problem to the same server with another computer. Therefore, it's not a firewall problem coming from the router.
- The admin of the server doesn't see any issues that could create this concern, and everybody else has access as they should.

This is the error message Git tells me:

```
ssh: connect to host ******* port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Result of command **netstat -plant | grep :22**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1248/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22
```

I was told that could be a problem with my iptables, and have tried to `sudo iptables -X` (and `-F`), with no luck. I have no idea how to manage this further...

EDIT:

As asked in the comments, I tried to run an ordinary SSH session in verbose mode. Here are the messages I have:

```
-$ ssh -v theuser@server.net
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to theuser@server.net [82.165.49.211] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 82.165.49.211 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host theuser@server.net port 22: Connection refused
```

Result of command **ls -al /var/run/**

```
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 25 root       root        820 jan 30 20:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root       root       4096 oct 14 22:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 acpid.pid
srw-rw-rw-  1 root       root          0 jan 30 20:49 acpid.socket
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi      avahi        80 jan 30 20:49 avahi-daemon
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 console
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 ConsoleKit
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 console-kit-daemon.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 crond.pid
----------  1 root       root          0 jan 30 20:49 crond.reboot
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       lp          120 jan 30 20:49 cups
drwxr-xr-x  2 messagebus messagebus   80 jan 30 20:48 dbus
srw-rw-rw-  1 root       root          0 jan 30 20:49 gdm_socket
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         40 jan 30 20:49 initramfs
drwxrwxrwt  3 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 mdm.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        135 jan 30 20:48 motd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         60 jan 30 20:48 mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql      root         80 jan 30 20:49 mysqld
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root        140 jan 30 20:49 network
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root        100 jan 30 20:49 NetworkManager
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 pglcmd.wd.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          5 jan 30 20:49 pgld.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         40 jan 30  2015 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root         80 jan 30 20:49 pm-utils
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         40 jan 30 20:49 pppconfig
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root        100 jan 30 20:49 resolvconf
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          4 jan 30 20:48 rsyslogd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root        320 jan 30 20:49 samba
srw-rw-rw-  1 root       root          0 jan 30 20:48 sdp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 sendsigs.omit.d
drwxrwxrwt  2 root       root        140 jan 30 20:49 shm
drwxr-xr-x  6 root       root        120 jan 30 20:49 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  6 root       root        160 jan 30 20:49 udev
drwx------  2 root       root         40 jan 30 20:49 udisks2
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          4 jan 30 20:48 upstart-file-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          4 jan 30 20:48 upstart-socket-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          4 jan 30 20:48 upstart-udev-bridge.pid
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root         60 jan 30 20:49 user
-rw-rw-r--  1 root       utmp       3840 jan 30 20:50 utmp
```

Content of **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** (without "#" comments lines)

```
Host *
# (...)
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling your firewall first and see if you can ssh? If it succeeds then it definitely is a bad firewall rule: `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: The error message says `uid=1000 pid=6098 comm="start ssh "`, which indicates it was running as uid 1000. Try `sudo service ssh restart`.

Comment: Can you test an ordinary ssh session with verbose on, to that server? `ssh -v username@192.168.1.201` use the server ip

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388499/how-can-i-run-git-push-pull-commands-with-ssh-verbose-mode) to enable ssh verbose mode within git.

Comment: @DevNull - I disabled my firewall with the command you showed me but I'm still unable to push to the server.I just have a message telling " the firewall is stopped & disabled during the boot system".

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I ran aswell your command to restart the ssh service, I got as answer this -> "stop: Unknown instance: ssh stop/pre-start, process 8957". I'm still unable to connect.

Comment: @Alan Here is the result I got when trying to connect to the server with the -v parameter ssh -v theuser.onlinehome.fr
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to theuser.onlinehome.fr [82.165.49.211] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 82.165.49.211 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host theuser.onlinehome.fr port 22: Connection refused

Comment: @Azuk Can you run this command and update your questions with the output `ls -al /var/run/`

Comment: @Azuk, ok permissions seem fine, try this: `ps -ef | egrep '(ssh|PID)'`, look for something like `/usr/sbin/sshd`, if running killing it `sudo kill -9 <PID>` and then run `sudo service ssh restart`. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Try with maximum verbosity (-vvv)

Comment: @DevNull It still doesn't work, with the first command I indeed get a process /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session  etc... It had the id of 2321, so I ran the command to kill it as root. I then restarted the SSH services. It returned `top: Unknown instance: 
ssh stop/pre-start, process 4543`
But that still doesn't work. However, there is something odd, after killing the PID and restarting the SSH services I ran again the command to see the SSH processes and the process still appear with the same orginal ID which is 2321.

Comment: @Alan I tested with maximum verbosity and the output is exactly the same as one single -v parameter...

Comment: It is possible that the server only has ssh enabled for git. Try getting the git to run ssh in verbose. (the link I posted)

Comment: I added the config file as I didn't have one in my .ssh folder and put the code as shown in the link. It seems It doesn't work. Here is what I have when I run again the command with -vvv `OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/geo/.ssh/config
/home/geo/.ssh/config line 2: unsupported log level '(QUIET|FATAL|ERROR|INFO|VERBOSE|DEBUG|DEBUG1|DEBUG2|DEBUG3)`

Comment: Regarding the `ps` output, the `netstat` output, and the `/var/run` listing, are these listings from the computer you're trying to connect _to_, or the computer you're connecting _from_?

Comment: Is the IP address correct? (You might have a stale DNS cache for some reason.) Is some option being applied through `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`? Post their content or try moving them out of the way.

Comment: @Kenster all the outputs you see here are from my PC. I personnaly don't have access to this server and nothing seems wrong with this server as I can connect to that one using another computer, connected through the same connection.It seems there is something wrong with my SSH on my computer. But I still don't know what exactly. I was told that could be something related to ip tables but I have no idea how to fix it and have found nothing on the internet till now, hence my post here...

Comment: @Gilles, I edited my first post to put the outputs of the two config files you asked me. At first I had no config file in the `~/.ssh/config`. I added this one as asked in a previous comment. You think I should move these files !?

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found a way to fix the issue I had. I found [this article about iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04). It helped me a lot to fix the issue.

The only thing I did is run the command

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Doing that has allowed me to push again on remote repositories and thus using ssh.
But I had to save that.

For this I run this other command to make all the changements due to the previous command persistent

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

I found that thanks the article linked previously.
I rebooted in the meantime and everything is working correctly.

Comment: you are flushing all ip-table entries here. Instead of that just stop iptables by running "sudo service iptables stop"